# Sprite Drawing Issue

Tags: java, sprite

When im using this code, the image draws (from the section of the spritesheet i defined), but it repaints it OVER the previous instance. i need the "image" to "move". Im using the paint method, with the Graphics to redraw the sprite defined in the init() method. Im just trying to create a "minion" that once it is added to the program, begins "walking" from the bottom left of the screen to the right, by itself (no user action moves it). I can currently get it to just take the image and "smudge" it across the bottom of the screen (it continuously paints it over itself)

(removed imports for simplicity)

```
 public class Main extends JFrame {

    BufferedImage sprite;
    int War_x = 10, War_y = 640, War_dx = 1;

    public Main()
    {
        //(X,Y) ---- (LEFT,UP)
        //Window theGUI = new Window();
        //JFrame theGUI = new JFrame();
        setSize(870,720);
        setTitle("Game");
        setBackground(Color.red);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        init();

    }
    public void init()
    {
        BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
        BufferedImage spriteSheet = null;
        System.out.println("bruh");
        try {
            spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("warrior.png");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(spriteSheet);

        sprite = ss.grabSprite(0,130,32,36);


    } 
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){

    g.drawImage(sprite, War_x, War_y,64, 64, null);
    warrior start = new warrior();
    start.start();
    repaint();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Main main = new Main();
}


public class warrior implements ActionListener{
    public Timer T = new Timer(100, this);

    public void start(){
        T.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        War_x += War_dx;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, do not recommend drawing directly onto the JFrame. That's one of the reasons you are having issues with "smudging/etc". Use a Canvas or something similar that's built for drawing. Also probably better to draw to something like a BufferedImage and just draw that to the screen instead of drawing to the screen directly.

Second, if you want to have it constantly move I would put it in a loop outside, and simply have the canvas updating automatically from a separate thread.

Here is a link to get you started with Threads https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: im still new to this, so ill use your suggestion to use a canvas. However, the issue with a loop is, i need there to be a delay, or FPS rate, so that the user actually sees the sprite moving. i tried using a timer for this, but im not all that great with timers.

Comment: If you put the drawing into a thread, you can make it very simple and just have something along the line of thead.sleep(). I'm not sure how complicated you want to go with this, but its probably your best bet.

Comment: how do i set up a thread? currently, i believe using thread.sleep() causes the whole frame to sleep. i plan on having multiple sprites on the screen moving independently of each other, so is this method still the best for this case?

Comment: A quick google search should give you lots of ways of implementing a thread. To specifically answer your question - You want a thread handling changes made to the canvas that is constantly updating (e.g. it updates as often as possible, if there is a change to the drawing).

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the sprite "move", you need to remove him from the canvas where he used to be, then draw him at his new location.

In order to actually do this, you may have to do something like this:

1. Clear Screen
2. Redraw Updated Background
3. Redraw Updated Entities

So for an actual situation, assuming your background is just a plain white rectangle that, where `canvasWidth` and `canvasHeight` are the width and height of your canvas, your paint method would look something like this:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    g.drawImage(sprite, War_x, War_y,64, 64, null);
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: thank you, this seems like a hassle, but if thats the best way, then alright. How do i exactly clear the screen?

Comment: If you're using the `Graphics` object, then `g.clearRect` might be your best bet. That'll just clear everything out in the rectangle, then you can redraw your backgrounds, characters, objects, etc.

Comment: Update: when i do this, it spams the "clear" and it doesn't show the sprite. i sometimes catch glimpses of the sprite inbetween clears, but it appears that the sprite is being pasted underneath the canvas i created